# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

DeclarationError: Undeclared Identifier, on Transfer(owner, addresses[i], _value; <<  for the word "Transfer" >>

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract distribution { 

mapping(address => uint) balances;

address private owner;

function distributeBlox(address[] addresses, uint256 _value) owner {
    for (uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        balances[owner] -= _value;
        balances[addresses[i]] += _value;
        Transfer(owner, addresses[i], _value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is Transfer supposed to be [an event](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#events)? You probably need to declare it with "event Transfer(...);".

Comment: Yep it works I added 
       event Transfer(
            address owner,
            address addresses,
            uint _value
            );
Now is giving me an issue saying that the gas requirement is infinite, but I will ask that on another question. Thank you

Comment: It's warning you about the gas because it has no idea how many addresses are in the array. If there are too many addresses you will reach maximum gas limit and it will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just add.

```
event Transfer(
        address owner,
        address addresses,
        uint _value
        );
```

Thanks guys!